# Updating a lot of Data in One Field using Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update one filled with a lot of data.

This is my table

[image]

I want to update `NameAlias` with new names for `Major` but this is my question if I have a lot of major names and ids how can I write a query that is good and short?
I know it should be something like this for one column.

```
Update Major Set NameAlias='Mathemathic' where IdMajor=1;
```

But what should I do if I have a lot of data for one field?

I want my result to be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a temp table containing the `id, NameAlias` accordingly like below.

```
select Id, NameAlias
into #TempTable
from (
  values(1, 'Mathemathic'),
        (2, 'Software'),
        (3, 'Painthing')
        -- The rest of values
)v(Id, NameAlias)
```

Then you can update the `Major` table

```
Update m
SET m.NameAlias = t.NameAlias 
  From Major m
  INNER JOIN #TempTable t on m.IdMajor = t.Id
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use case when expression -

```
Update Major Set NameAlias=
case when namemajor='Math' then 'Mathemathic'
when namemajor='Computer' then 'Software' 
when namemajor='Art' then 'Painthing'
when namemajor='History' then 'FranceHistory' 
when namemajor='Music' then 'Piano' end
```

Comment: what is the last then? if id remove it I get the error

Comment: From my point of view, using `CASE WHEN` is not good for coding practice.

Comment: @Phong is it ok to use it when I have a lot of data too?

Comment: @Nazanin Did you check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60144750/9071943) ?

Comment: @Phong yes I want to know which one is better?

Comment: Imagine you have 1000 records, and you have to copy/paste `CASE WHEN THEN' 1000 times. Besides, You are hard to select to support debugger purposes. While you use my solution, you can debug, select, reduce redundant copy/paste.

Comment: @Phong I have a question about your answer in select after From I should write the table's name?

Comment: Yes, you just need to create the table then insert normally. like `create table aa (it int, NameAlias varchar(20)) insert into aa (id, NameAlias) values(1, 'Mathemathic'),
        (2, 'Software'),
        (3, 'Painthing')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207519/discussion-between-nazanin-and-phong).

Comment: @Fahmi . . . I'm upvoting because creating a temporary table to do this is utterly unnecessary.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff How about debug purposes?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a temporary table to do this.  Just use a derived table in the `update` query:

```
update m
    set m.NameAlias = v.newAlias
  from Major m join
       (values(1, 'Mathematic'),
              (2, 'Software'),
              (3, 'Painting')
       ) v(idMajor, newAlias)
       on m.IdMajor = v.IdMajor;
```

Comment: what is t.Idmajor?? we do not have this

Comment: @Nazanin . . . That should be `v`.  I fixed it.